# Recycler checked item crash

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

```
public class SubcategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SubcategoryAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    Context mContext;
    private List<SubcategoryData> firstList;

    boolean bind;
    private ArrayList<SubcategoryData> subcategory_checked;
    private List<Boolean> isCheckedArray;


    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        int subcategoryId;
        int status;

        @BindView(R.id.tv_subCategoryName)
        TextView name;
        @BindView(R.id.cb_chooseSub)
        CheckBox chooseSub;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        }
    }

    public SubcategoryAdapter(List<SubcategoryData> firstList, Context mContext) {
        this.firstList = firstList;
        subcategory_checked = new ArrayList<>(firstList.size());

        for (int i = 0; i < firstList.size(); i++)

        isCheckedArray = new ArrayList<Boolean>(firstList.size());

        for (int i = 0; i < firstList.size(); i++) {

            isCheckedArray.add(false);
        }
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @Override
    public SubcategoryAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_subcategory, parent, false);

        return new SubcategoryAdapter.MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final SubcategoryAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        bind = true;
        final SubcategoryData listq = firstList.get(position);
        if (listq == null) {
            return;
        }

        holder.name.setText(listq.getTitle());
        holder.subcategoryId = listq.getId();
        holder.chooseSub.setChecked(isCheckedArray.get(position));

        holder.chooseSub.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                if (!bind) {

                    isCheckedArray.set(position, isChecked);

                    if (isChecked) {

                        subcategory_checked.add(position, listq);
                        SubcategoryData subcategoryData = new SubcategoryData();
                        subcategoryData.setId(holder.subcategoryId);
                        subcategoryData.setTitle(holder.name.getText().toString());
                        notifyDataSetChanged();


                    } else {

                        subcategory_checked.remove(position);

                    }

                }
            }

        });

        bind = false;

    }

    public ArrayList<SubcategoryData> getSubsIDsArray() {

        return subcategory_checked;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return firstList.size();
    }
}
```

I am tring to save checked item in my recyclerview >> but my problem is that when check item position 0 must check positiom 1 after > and if uchecked position 0 also must uncheck position 1 after  >> if check position 3 after 0 app crash .. amd if an un check position 3 after uchecked 1 and 2 app crach with error Invalid index 1, size is 0.

Comment: Instead of `position` use `getAdapterPosition()`.

Comment: Do not make the position as final. Instead use holder.getAdapterPosition() which gives you the right position of the clicked item in the recyclerView

Comment: @ItapuVinay .. thanks guys  uncheck last checked item solved .. but i still if check item 3 after 1 app crash